# ERROR: Asset package include 'C:\Users\jody\apktool\framework\1.apk' not found

Tags: android, command-line, apktool

I need apk tool for repacking my app.So I install it on windows and in command line type this instruction

```
apktool b decoded myapp.apk
```

but I recieve this error

```
enter code here I: Copying classes.dex file...
I: Checking whether resources has changed...
I: Building resources...
ERROR: Asset package include 'C:\Users\jody\apktool\framework\1.apk' not found.
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec command: [aapt, p, --min-sdk-version, 8, --target-sdk-version, 17, -F, C:\Users\jody\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL8545160768118157496.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, C:\Users\jody\apktool\framework\1.apk, -S, C:\Users\jody\Desktop\RV2013\result\res, -M, C:\Users\jody\Desktop\RV2013\result\AndroidManifest.xml]
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResourcesFull(Androlib.java:358)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResources(Androlib.java:283)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:206)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:176)
    at brut.apktool.Main.cmdBuild(Main.java:228)
    at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:79)
Caused by: brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec command: [aapt, p, --min-sdk-version, 8, --target-sdk-version, 17, -F, C:\Users\jody\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL8545160768118157496.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, C:\Users\jody\apktool\framework\1.apk, -S, C:\Users\jody\Desktop\RV2013\result\res, -M, C:\Users\jody\Desktop\RV2013\result\AndroidManifest.xml]
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.aaptPackage(AndrolibResources.java:357)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResourcesFull(Androlib.java:336)
    ... 5 more
  Caused by: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec command: [aapt, p, --min-sdk-version, 8, --target-sdk-version, 17, -F, C:\Users\jody\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL8545160768118157496.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, C:\Users\jody\apktool\framework\1.apk, -S, C:\Users\jody\Desktop\RV2013\result\res, -M, C:\Users\jody\Desktop\RV2013\result\AndroidManifest.xml]
    at brut.util.OS.exec(OS.java:89)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.aaptPackage(AndrolibResources.java:355)
    ... 6 more
```

Now I want ask how i can fix this error?

Comment: Is this the only output you get after running apktool?

Comment: No. The output was longer than this. I just put the main error part.

Comment: I need the full log in order to help, please post it.

Comment: I edit the post and put full output.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. :)

Comment: What version of apktool are you using?

Comment: The version of apktool is 2.0.3

Comment: Do you have 1.apk in this path: 'C:\Users\jody\apktool\framework\1.apk' ?

Comment: Yes.I have 1.apk in that path

Comment: Please remove it, and run apktool again

Comment: I remove 1.apk and run apktool again but unfortunately I got same error.

Comment: Weird. Can you try to decode and rebuild another apk just for test?

Comment: Yes,I tried another app too . Actually I got this problem only when I want packing files to apk format.unpacking of apk files are done without any error.

Comment: Sorry for these "trial and error" comments, but that's very weird. Are you sure that you have the right to write to 'C:\Users\jody\apktool\framework\'? Also are you 100% sure that the computer you are using with apktool is connected to internet? (pay attention if you are using a VM for example)

Comment: What do you mean of have right for write 'C:\Users\jody\apktool\framework'? I can remove and add file to this folder.Do I need special permission?

Comment: I am sure about Internet connection.

Comment: Can you please try to update apktool to the latest version 2.1.0? https://bitbucket.org/iBotPeaches/apktool/downloads/apktool_2.1.0.jar

Comment: Ok,Finally the error is disappear.Thank You.But I have another problem ,I don't see apk file in the folder.This command don't make apk file.the output is I: Using Apktool 2.1.0
I: Checking whether resources has changed...
I: Building apk file...

Comment: I'll write an aswer so you can accept it. Your new apk is in the dist folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: update to the latest version of apktool (2.1.0 at the time of writing).

The new apk is in the "dist" folder.

Remember to sign it with testsign.jar before installing it on your device.

EDIT: remember to use zipalign too!

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Your answer really help me.

Comment: I'm here to help. Happy reverse engineering :)